# Download Windows Phone app through asp website

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-8

I have an asp website which I would like users to be able to download a Windows Phone 8 app from. The app needs to store a unique user account from each different user which downloads it. Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In-house deployment of Windows Phone 8 applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144069/in-house-deployment-of-windows-phone-8-applications)

Comment: I doubt you can modify the distributable for each user download, as this would break the signing of the package

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to store a unique id in .xap file for every user who downloads from your website. But you can try this. Assign a unique number/ID to a user every time user downloads from your website. Ask the user to enter this number/ID as authentication code when you start your app. And cross check this number. By this way you can also track number of downloads and number of users who tried your app.